# Creating "overlay" buttons in A-frame?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I am creating an Augmented Reality "gallery" of photographs from the Trans-Mississippi International Exposition of 1898 held here in Omaha. I have created a gallery in a 360 degree arrangement of three tiers, two with a dozen images separated b 30 degrees, one with six images separated by 60 degrees.  I want to create one or more "buttons" to activate different features (still to be determined).  I have been searching high and low and experimenting with several different approaches, none of which work all that well, one especially "goes nuts" on my Samsung S20 test phone, jumping all over the screen.

I tried the  tag, but that was no help.

Does anyone have a "simple" away to add some control buttons over the top of the  layer that would work in A-frame AR?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To be clear, you want 2D HTML buttons over the native `AR` mode which would change the photospheres / plane texuters?

Comment: 2D HTML? Yes.  Still working on what I want the buttons to do: change display, play and stop audi.  Looking for examples of code. Came across a Babylon JS Youtube tutorial, but it is in a language I don't understand and the code used is only partially visible.